# Can one use SetWindowLongPtr + GWLP_USERDATA to store data (not pointer)

Tags: c, winapi

I know one can use SetWindowLongPtr + GWLP_USERDATA to store a pointer which points to some data.
But could one store the data directly, for example "a handle", "a bool, an "int" or other larger data.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, it says:

*Sets new extra information that is private to the application, such as handles or pointers.*

, so I guess to store a handle is OK. I also used this method to store an RGB value without problem.
But I don't know if this is a good idea to do things like this. And can we store other data which is large (for example, a structure)?

p.s: The motivation of this question is: When I create a dialog window, I want to store data for each of its controls. Of course I can use static variables in the window procedure and pass pointer (to them) to SetWindowLongPtr function. But this is not "perfect" in theory, because when the dialog window is closed, I don't need these data anymore. Of course, in practice, the data I need to use is very small, and I should not care about the usage of memory. But I still like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: There is also Set/Get/RemoveProp http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`SetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function can store a piece of data which has the same size as `LONG_PTR` (most likely 32bit or 64bit). If your data can be stored in that size, you're fine. I.e. a bool would be fine, so would most handles (since handles tend to be pointers, too).

A typical RGB value would work as well since it's stored as three bytes (one byte per color component) or four bytes (an extra byte for the alpha channel).

If you need more space than this, you should allocate a structure somewhere else and store a pointer to that structure.

Answer (score 9):

You only need one pointer to store anything you want.  Declare a struct with the data you want to store.  Allocate it before the CreateWindowEx() call and pass the pointer as the last argument.  You get it back in your window procedure for the WM_CREATE message, CREATESTRUCT.lpCreateParams field.  Now call SetWindowsLongPtr to store that pointer.

Anytime you need it back, use GetWindowlongPtr to recover the pointer to the struct.  You'll need to cleanup again, use the WM_NCDESTROY message to release the pointer.

Note that this is a standard technique used in C++ class libraries that wrap the winapi.  Do consider using one of them instead of spinning this yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure: Suppose I create a window inside a function, say function1, and inside function1, I also declare a struct and pass a pointer to it to the last argument of CreateWidnowEx. Then when it exits function1, and I use GetWindowlongPtr, then I will get garbage value of the struct right? (Because that struct is a local variable.) So I have to declare this struct variable as global or static variable, right?

Comment: Of course, don't store pointers to local variables.  Okay for a modal dialog, but that's a corner case.